# After forking bash with forkpty and execvp, bash does not respond to SIGINT

Tags: c++, node.js, bash, fork, execvp

#### Background

I'm currently writing an terminal emulator for a text editor that is written in Node.js (Javascript). The application uses C++ to fork a shell and communicate with it in the backend. The code that forks the shell was written by another developer who does not seem to be maintaining his project anymore. That left me with no other choice but to try and fix the problem myself. I've gone through his code line by line to the point where I understand most of what it is doing.

#### Problem

I can't figure out why bash won't send the SIGINT signal to it's sub processes. Everything else works perfectly. I can communicate with my shell instance in Node.js and run commands. However if I write the signal interrupt escape code ('\x03') to the fd of the pty, the SIGINT signal isn't sent. All I see is `^C` in the terminal display. Certain commands like `ping` will interpret it and stop. Commands like `cat`, `python`, or `java` do not stop and will just show `^C`.

Example:

```
user:example user$ cat
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

#### Code

First forkpty is used to get a pty instance. Then, the pty instance calls execvp to replace the process with the shell process. In this instance, execvp launches with `execvp('/bin/bash', {'/bin/bash', '--login'})`.

```
NAN_METHOD(PtyFork) {
  Nan::HandleScope scope;

  if (info.Length() != 9
      || !info[0]->IsString() // file
      || !info[1]->IsArray() // args
      || !info[2]->IsArray() // env
      || !info[3]->IsString() // cwd
      || !info[4]->IsNumber() // cols
      || !info[5]->IsNumber() // rows
      || !info[6]->IsNumber() // uid
      || !info[7]->IsNumber() // gid
      || !info[8]->IsFunction() // onexit
  ) {
    return Nan::ThrowError(
      "Usage: pty.fork(file, args, env, cwd, cols, rows, uid, gid, onexit)");
  }

  // file
  String::Utf8Value file(info[0]->ToString());

  // args
  int i = 0;
  Local<Array> argv_ = Local<Array>::Cast(info[1]);
  int argc = argv_->Length();
  int argl = argc + 1 + 1;
  char **argv = new char*[argl];
  argv[0] = strdup(*file);
  argv[argl-1] = NULL;
  for (; i < argc; i++) {
    String::Utf8Value arg(argv_->Get(Nan::New<Integer>(i))->ToString());
    argv[i+1] = strdup(*arg);
  }

  // env
  i = 0;
  Local<Array> env_ = Local<Array>::Cast(info[2]);
  int envc = env_->Length();
  char **env = new char*[envc+1];
  env[envc] = NULL;
  for (; i < envc; i++) {
    String::Utf8Value pair(env_->Get(Nan::New<Integer>(i))->ToString());
    env[i] = strdup(*pair);
  }

  // cwd
  String::Utf8Value cwd_(info[3]->ToString());
  char *cwd = strdup(*cwd_);

  // size
  struct winsize winp;
  winp.ws_col = info[4]->IntegerValue();
  winp.ws_row = info[5]->IntegerValue();
  winp.ws_xpixel = 0;
  winp.ws_ypixel = 0;

  // uid / gid
  int uid = info[6]->IntegerValue();
  int gid = info[7]->IntegerValue();

  // fork the pty
  int master = -1;
  char name[40];
  pid_t pid = pty_forkpty(&master, name, NULL, &winp);

  if (pid) {
    for (i = 0; i < argl; i++) free(argv[i]);
    delete[] argv;
    for (i = 0; i < envc; i++) free(env[i]);
    delete[] env;
    free(cwd);
  }

  switch (pid) {
    case -1:
      return Nan::ThrowError("forkpty(3) failed.");
    case 0:
      if (strlen(cwd)) chdir(cwd);

      if (uid != -1 && gid != -1) {
        if (setgid(gid) == -1) {
          perror("setgid(2) failed.");
          _exit(1);
        }
        if (setuid(uid) == -1) {
          perror("setuid(2) failed.");
          _exit(1);
        }
      }

      pty_execvpe(argv[0], argv, env);

      perror("execvp(3) failed.");
      _exit(1);
    default:
      if (pty_nonblock(master) == -1) {
        return Nan::ThrowError("Could not set master fd to nonblocking.");
      }

      Local<Object> obj = Nan::New<Object>();
      Nan::Set(obj,
        Nan::New<String>("fd").ToLocalChecked(),
        Nan::New<Number>(master));
      Nan::Set(obj,
        Nan::New<String>("pid").ToLocalChecked(),
        Nan::New<Number>(pid));
      Nan::Set(obj,
        Nan::New<String>("pty").ToLocalChecked(),
        Nan::New<String>(name).ToLocalChecked());

      pty_baton *baton = new pty_baton();
      baton->exit_code = 0;
      baton->signal_code = 0;
      baton->cb.Reset(Local<Function>::Cast(info[8]));
      baton->pid = pid;
      baton->async.data = baton;

      uv_async_init(uv_default_loop(), &baton->async, pty_after_waitpid);

      uv_thread_create(&baton->tid, pty_waitpid, static_cast<void*>(baton));

      return info.GetReturnValue().Set(obj);
  }

  return info.GetReturnValue().SetUndefined();
}

/**
 * execvpe
 */

// execvpe(3) is not portable.
// http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/execvpe.html
static int
pty_execvpe(const char *file, char **argv, char **envp) {
  char **old = environ;
  environ = envp;
  int ret = execvp(file, argv);
  environ = old;
  return ret;
}

/**
 * Nonblocking FD
 */

static int
pty_nonblock(int fd) {
  int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
  if (flags == -1) return -1;
  return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
}

/**
 * pty_waitpid
 * Wait for SIGCHLD to read exit status.
 */

static void
pty_waitpid(void *data) {
  int ret;
  int stat_loc;

  pty_baton *baton = static_cast<pty_baton*>(data);

  errno = 0;

  if ((ret = waitpid(baton->pid, &stat_loc, 0)) != baton->pid) {
    if (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR) {
      return pty_waitpid(baton);
    }
    if (ret == -1 && errno == ECHILD) {
      // XXX node v0.8.x seems to have this problem.
      // waitpid is already handled elsewhere.
      ;
    } else {
      assert(false);
    }
  }

  if (WIFEXITED(stat_loc)) {
    baton->exit_code = WEXITSTATUS(stat_loc); // errno?
  }

  if (WIFSIGNALED(stat_loc)) {
    baton->signal_code = WTERMSIG(stat_loc);
  }

  uv_async_send(&baton->async);
}

/**
 * pty_after_waitpid
 * Callback after exit status has been read.
 */

static void
#if NODE_VERSION_AT_LEAST(0, 11, 0)
pty_after_waitpid(uv_async_t *async) {
#else
pty_after_waitpid(uv_async_t *async, int unhelpful) {
#endif
  Nan::HandleScope scope;
  pty_baton *baton = static_cast<pty_baton*>(async->data);

  Local<Value> argv[] = {
    Nan::New<Integer>(baton->exit_code),
    Nan::New<Integer>(baton->signal_code),
  };

  Local<Function> cb = Nan::New<Function>(baton->cb);
  baton->cb.Reset();
  memset(&baton->cb, -1, sizeof(baton->cb));
  Nan::Callback(cb).Call(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 2, argv);

  uv_close((uv_handle_t *)async, pty_after_close);
}

/**
 * pty_after_close
 * uv_close() callback - free handle data
 */

static void
pty_after_close(uv_handle_t *handle) {
  uv_async_t *async = (uv_async_t *)handle;
  pty_baton *baton = static_cast<pty_baton*>(async->data);
  delete baton;
}

static pid_t
pty_forkpty(int *amaster, char *name,
            const struct termios *termp,
            const struct winsize *winp) {
  return forkpty(amaster, name, (termios *)termp, (winsize *)winp);
}
```

#### What I've Tried

I have tried using execvp to call `exec -l bash` instead. That launches bash but does not solve the issue.
I have tried writing to the fd directly within C++ just incase it was Node.js. Same issue of seeing `^C` but not registering a `SIGINT`.

The only thing that does work is to use another shell such as zsh. When using zsh, the `SIGINT` is properly sent and the subprocesses stop. Something else that is odd is that bash shells launched from ZSH don't experience this issue. In other words, if I fork zsh and call the command `exec bash` (or `exec -l bash`), then that new bash instance will send the `SIGINT` signal like it is supposed to.

I know it is not just me because my application is public and multiple users have reported this issue. Some on Linux, some on OS X. This is a major issue, so it would be greatly appreciated if someone could point out what is going on here.

#### Additional Information

Print out of `stty -a`:

```
user:example user$ stty -a
speed 9600 baud; 15 rows; 159 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
        -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
        -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel -iutf8
        -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
        -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
        eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
        min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
        stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Comment: Did you try `setsid` before exec bash ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: call `setsid` before exec

---

Signals are sent to active process group of the session which associate to the slave pty. By calling `setsid`, a session is created which associate to the pty, otherwise no session was created, so no signal will be emitted.

Comment: I added `setsid()` just before my exec call and I get -1 as a return as well as a message `Operation not permitted`.

Comment: Hmm, can you try use `TIOCSCTTY` to set the created tty the controlling terminal of the child process ?

Comment: I was able to somewhat solve my issue by declaring `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL)` before calling forkpty(2). However, I am still experiencing this issue with commands like `cat /dev/zero`. `cat` by itself can be interrupted. I have tried both `setsid` and `ioctl(master, TIOCSCTTY, NULL)` in the child pty process just before the `exec` call. Both return with "Operation not permitted".